# Google Map image use in public presentation

Tags: copyright, terms-of-service, fair-use

The IP statement supplied by Google Maps outlining permissible use of images of their maps is rather vague (to me at least) see link (https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html). 
They give clear permission for "non-commercial use" in internal reports, presentations, etc., and suggest that one should reference "fair use", but I have difficulty understanding these terms as applied to their permissions. Consider this link: 
http://cogentlegal.com/blog/2011/10/tips-and-tricks-for-attorneys-to-use-google-maps-and-google-earth/ 
where two attorneys discuss using Google map presentations in litigation, clearly a "commercial use" in one sense, but is it "commercial use" as Google would define it? I am asking because I wish to use google map images in a presentation at a scientific conference, but am presenting research completed at a for-profit company at a meeting one must pay the organizing scientific society to attend (speakers are not paid). I am quite sure Google would be "cool" with this (their word), but I cannot find explicit permission for this use in their statement (linked above). I would note that if one contacts them with an inquire they reply "Due to limited resources and high demand, we're unable to sign any letter or contract specifying that your project or use has our explicit permission. As long as you follow the guidance on this link, and attribute the Content correctly, feel free to move forward with your project". Ok, but without some specific reference demonstrating their permission or that my use is not what they consider"commercial" I am prohibited by my company form using their material ... and that I cannot find. I would be grateful for any help in the reading of their permissions to bring light on this.

Comment: Sure, Google probably has an alternative (and authoritve) perspective. Have you asked them?